# devDependencies ignored in npm?

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I am the author of two npm modules, both with devDependencies.
The first one is simpleDbLayer. Install it:

```
npm install simpledblayer
```

The downloaded `package.js` file has devDependencies matching what is in the [git repository](https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer/blob/master/package.json):

```
//...
"devDependencies": {
  "simpleschema": "0.3.x"
},
//...
```

Unfortunately, `nodeunit test.js` will fail because `simpleschema` wasn't installed (as it should have been). From the manual:

> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies. With the --production flag, npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies

Even weirder (and this is the really strange issue I am most affected by) is my other module, simpledblayer-mongo:

```
npm install simpledblayer-mongo
```

In he installed `package.js` file, I have:

```
"devDependencies": {},
```

Which doesn't match what was actually published, [which contains](https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer-mongo/blob/master/package.json):

```
"devDependencies": {
  "simpleschema": "0.3.x",
  "simpleschema-mongo": "0.3.x"
},
```

Needless to say simpleschema and simpleschema-mongo is not installed.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by default it will install the devDependencies but only for your project (devDependencies in your `package.json`), not for modules in the npm repository.

If you want the devDependencies of your dependencies, force it by passing `--dev` to the npm command:

```
npm install simpledblayer --dev
```

Also, when you have the environment variable NODE_ENV set to production, it won't install the devDependencies either (not even the ones in your `package.json`).

Comment: The problem I am having is that _it's not installing devDependencies for my own project_! I install `simpledblayer`, and `simpledblayer`'s devDependencies are not installed...

Comment: You may be the module author, but you are downloading it from the npm repository. What I meant by your project is when you issue an `npm install` in a directory where your code already resides.

Comment: I am confused. The use case I have is simple: I am in a new, virgin empty home directory. I run `npm install simpledblayer-mongo`. Then I get into that directory, and run `npm test`. The tests fail because devDependencies of simpledblayer-mongo are not installed. If this use case doesn't work, what _is_ the use case that actually does work?

Comment: When your code is already in your machine, and you just want to install its dependencies you issue an `npm install` (without any module name). In this case, the devDependencies will be installed as well (the ones in your package.json, not the ones in the package.json of your dependencies).

Comment: To put it simply, just pass the --dev parameter and it will install all the devDependencies (the ones in your `package.json` and the ones in every `package.json` that your modules depends on).

Comment: Hang on... have a look here: https://gist.github.com/mercmobily/a33dd80f0463f1c88599 So, when I first install simpledblayer it only installs the direct dependencies. Then I get into the module's directory, run a `npm install`, and it _actually_ installs the devDependencies...?!? Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes, in the first command you downloaded the project from npm respository. In this case it will only install the dependencies (if you don't use --dev parameter). In the second command, you already had the project in your machine and was only installing its dependencies (you didn't pass any module names to `npm install`). In THIS case, it will download the devDependencies by default.

Comment: This is insanity... is this clearly explained somewhere in the NPM documentation...?

Comment: Plus, any idea about the second part of the question? When installing `simpledblayer-mongo`, in package.js the `devDependencies` attribute is set to `{}`... like ths:` "devDependencies": {},` whereas in my repo I _swear_ I have two dependencies!

Comment: @Merc, as Victor already said, npm doesn't know if you are the author or not, if you simply do `npm install <package>`. If you need to work on its source, then you should *not* use `npm install <package>` but rather `git clone` and `cd <package> && npm install`. Unfortunately, I don't think the behavior of `npm install <package>` is documented explicitly, while the behavior of `cd <package> && npm install` is documented fairly clearly at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description

Comment: @Timothy I am not sure how your answer follows up at all from my latest comment, where what is published in npm and what is downloaded differs in terms of devDependencies. I have no problem understanding that authorship doesn't change anything.